# Can't call any JNI functionality from android_main in NDK project

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm porting an existing C++ game to Android NDK, using a Visual Studio template. I've hit the phase of implementing functionality which needs to be routed through Java, and I cannot get the runtime to allow calls from C++ code into the JVM.

I have a Java class, JNIActivityBridge, which extends NativeActivity and provides some helpful code. From onCreate, I can call into a C++ native function, and that function can in turn seamlessly call back into Java. I've used this to verify that my basic JNI code is correct and everything I've been putting into this particular shim works just fine.

```
//everything here works totally fine and I have no problems
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL         Java_com_kata_JNIActivityBridge_InitializeJNIStuff(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    JniEnv = env;
    ActivityBridge = obj;
    PlatformSupportClass = env->FindClass("com/kata/PlatformSupport");
    ActivityBridgeClass = env->FindClass("com/kata/JNIActivityBridge");
    TestMethod = env->GetMethodID(ActivityBridgeClass, "AlertTest", "()V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(ActivityBridge, TestMethod);
    LOGI("JNI Active");
    return;
}
```

What I cannot get to work is any JNI call from the main application thread (code that traces its callstack back to android_main). I've called AttachCurrentThread but FindClass fails, GetMethodID fails if I use a jclass cached from the activity shim, and of course I can't call into Java. At this point I simply need to invoke some simple Java functions while this game is running and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get back into the JVM from my main thread. What do I need in order to use Java functions from this thread/context?

```
void android_main(struct android_app* state) {
    struct engine engine;

    memset(&engine, 0, sizeof(engine));
    state->userData = &engine;
    state->onAppCmd = engine_handle_cmd;
    state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input;
    engine.app = state;
    AppEngine = &engine;

    Jvm = state->activity->vm;
    state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&engine.jni, nullptr);
    //--- none of the following calls work here ---
    jclass cl = engine.jni->FindClass("com/kata/PlatformSupport");
    jmethodID mt = engine.jni->GetStaticMethodID(cl, "TestCallAdd", "(I)I");
    jint add = engine.jni->CallStaticIntMethod(cl, mt, 3);

    if(state->savedState != NULL) {
        // We are starting with a previous saved state; restore from it.
        engine.state = *(struct saved_state*)state->savedState;
    }

    GameMain(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: From an old Google groups discussion: _"[This] will allow you to only access android framework classes (android.app.Activity etc...) but this default class loader can't access your Java classes (not part of android framework)

you need to retrieve the classloader from the activity (using the method `getClassLoader()`) and use the `loadClass` method of the class loader (just cast the jobject returned to a jclass)"_